# apply a user defined function to a groupby in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My dataframe `df` looks something like this

```
review_id   user_id  prod_id    review
0               10      5       this restaurant is the best.
1               30      10      Worst food.
2               10      15      Best place!
3               30      5       the food is too expensive.
4               30      10      Yummy! I love it.
```

I now defined a function `ACS` that I want to use to calculate the average content similarity of each user. I wrote the function as follows:

```
def ACS(rvw1,rvw2):
    rvw1=rvw1.replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace("?","").replace("!","").lower()
    rvw2=rvw2.replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace("?","").replace("!","").lower()
    rvw1words = rvw1.split()
    rvw2words = rvw2.split()
    allwords = list(set(rvw1words) | set(rvw2words))
    rvw1freq=[]
    rvw2freq=[]
    for word in allwords:
        rvw1freq.append(rvw1words.count(word))
        rvw2freq.append(rvw2words.count(word))
    return np.dot(rvw1freq,rvw2freq)/(np.linalg.norm(rvw1freq)*np.linalg.norm(rvw2freq))
```

This function takes two strings as an input and returns the similarity between them on a scale of 0 to 1. My aim is to calculate the content similarity of each user so I formed a groupby as follow:

```
grouped = df.groupby('user_id')['review']
```

Now i want to apply my `ACS`function on each group (something like `grouped.ACS()`). But the problem is that ACS takes two strings as input and calculate their similarity. But each group in the groupby may have more than 2 review strings. What should I do to apply this function to each group such that it takes all the reviews from a group and calculate their content similarity.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.merge` to get the cartesian product of rows and then use `pd.DataFrame.apply` to apply your function:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Helper function to get combinations of a dataframe and their cosine similarity
def groupSimilarity(df):
    combinations = (df.assign(dummy=1)
                     .merge(df.assign(dummy=1), on="dummy")
                     .drop("dummy", axis=1))
    similarity = combinations.apply(lambda x: ACS(x["review_x"], x["review_y"]), axis=1)
    combinations.loc[:, "similarity"] = similarity
    return combinations

# apply function to each group
grouped = (df.groupby("user_id")
            .apply(combinations)
            .reset_index())

# >>> grouped[["review_id_x", "review_id_y", "user_id_x", "user_id_y", "distance"]]
#     review_id_x  review_id_y  user_id_x  user_id_y  distance
# 0             0            0         10         10  1.000000
# 1             0            2         10         10  0.316228
# 2             2            0         10         10  0.316228
# 3             2            2         10         10  1.000000
# 4             1            1         30         30  1.000000
# 5             1            3         30         30  0.316228
# 6             1            4         30         30  0.000000
# 7             3            1         30         30  0.316228
# 8             3            3         30         30  1.000000
# 9             3            4         30         30  0.000000
# 10            4            1         30         30  0.000000
# 11            4            3         30         30  0.000000
# 12            4            4         30         30  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for answering. But I want to apply the function on a group. For example, one group with ```user_id``` 30 contains 3 reviews: ```Worst food.```, ```the food is too expensive.``` and ```Yummy! I love it.```. Now I somehow want to apply ```ACS``` function on this group so that it calculates the cosine similarity between all the three reviews.I might need to change my ```ACS``` function but I dont know how.  Your solution compares each review with every other review and applies the function on each pair and not on a groupby. I want to apply the funtion on the groupby.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I updated my answer to incorporate the application to individual groups. I added a helper function that can  be applied to each group of a grouped dataframe.